# Why is this code reporting function object is not scriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
@pytest.fixture
def settings():
    with open('../config.yaml') as yaml_stream:
        return yaml.load(stream=yaml_stream)    


@pytest.fixture
def viewers(settings):
    try:
        data = requests.get(settings['endpoints']['viewers']).json()
        return data[0]['viewers']
    except Exception:
        print('ERROR retrieving viewers')
        raise(SystemExit)


@pytest.fixture
def viewers_buffer_health(viewers):
    print(viewers)
    viewers_with_buffer_health = {}
    for viewer in viewers:
        try:
            data = requests.get(settings['endpoints']['node_buffer_health']).replace('<NODE_ID>', viewer)
        except Exception as e:
            print('ERROR retrieving buffer_health for {}'.format(viewer))
            raise(SystemExit)
        viewers_with_buffer_health[viewer] = data[0]['avg_buffer_health']
    return viewers_with_buffer_health
```

The fixture `viewers_buffer_health` is failing all the time on the `requests` because `'function' object is not subscriptable`

Other times I have seen such error it has been because I was calling a variable and a function by the same name, but it's not the case (or I'm blind at all).

Although it shouldn't matter, the output of `viewers` is a list like `['a4a6b1c0-e98a-42c8-abe9-f4289360c220', '152bff1c-e82e-49e1-92b6-f652c58d3145', '55a06a01-9956-4d7c-bfd0-5a2e6a27b62b']`

Comment: What is `settings`?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams just added it

Comment: Okay, well, it's a function. You can't subscript that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it's a fixture, you can pass it to another fixture. For example, the fixture `viewers` uses `settings` as well, and it doesn't complain.

Comment: `viewers()` has an argument called `settings`. *That* is what it's using.

Comment: Yeah you forgot the `settings` parameter in `def viewers_buffer_health`

Comment: omfg, I'm idiot xDD As I said, I was blind at all xD @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams put that as an answer so that I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `viewers_buffer_health()` doesn't have a local definition for `settings` it is using the function defined previously. If it is meant to work in the same manner as `viewers()` then you will need to add a `settings` argument to its current set of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`settings` is a function.

```
data = requests.get(settings()['endpoints']['node_buffer_health']).replace('<NODE_ID>', viewer)
```